# would having php code before doctype make browser to go into quirks mode?

Tags: php, session, doctype, quirks-mode

As have been discussed in one of the posts here; there was someone who dynamically attached javacript code above the doctype declaration and it then made his browser to go into quirks mode..I am currently in the same condition, only in my case I am dealing with PHP code snippet below that **has** to be inserted above the doctype otherwise I would get PHP "whitespace" error.

```
<?php session_start();
if(!session_is_registered("reg")){
    header("location:page1.php");
}?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

So would that bring my browser into quirks mode? If it would, is there any workaround? appreciate any help/suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. PHP code is processed before the browser consumes it. Just make sure you don't send any trailing characters after your PHP or echo anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can have PHP before the doctype, the PHP won't exist when it really matters. If you're having some white-space show up, just reformat the doctype to just after the closing `?>`.

```
<?php

  $var = 'foo';

?><!DOCTYPE html>
```

As long as you're not outputting anything, the browser will never even know there was PHP before the DOCTYPE to begin with, and what the browser doesn't know won't hurt it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Placing doctype at the same line may help:

```
<?php session_start();
if(!session_is_registered("reg")){
    header("location:page1.php");
    die(); // presumably you want this
}?><!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

No because the php code never gets printed. To check this right click on the page and check the actual generated html source code for the page. Javascript is different because it actually gets printed.